# How can I open the sub items in a list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I'm using this script to open my hamburger menu. This works fine, but some list items have subitems. How would I have to adjust the script so that the subitems open when an item is clicked?

```js
  function myResponsive() {
   var x = document.getElementById("myMenu");
   if (x.className === "menu-hori") {
    x.className += " responsive";
   } else {
    x.className = "menu-hori";
   }
  }
```

```css
 .menu-hori{
  width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: table;
  z-index: 100;
  background: grey;
 }
 
 .menu-hori ul {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
 }

 .menu-hori ul ul {
     opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 160%;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
 }
 
 .menu-hori ul ul ul {
  top: 0%;
  left: 160%;
 }
 
 .menu-hori ul ul li:hover > ul {
     top: 0%;
     left: 100%;
     opacity: 1;
     visibility: visible;
 }
 
 .menu-hori ul li:hover > ul {
     opacity: 1;
     top: 100%;
     visibility: visible;
 }
 
 .menu-hori ul li {
     float: left;
     position: relative;
 }
 
 
 .menu-hori ul ul li { float: none; }

 .menu-hori ul li {
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .menu-hori ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 }

 .menu-hori ul li:hover { background-color: #069CDE; }

 .menu-hori ul li a:hover { background-color: #069CDE; }
 
 .menu-hori span.dropBottom,span.dropRight {
   display: block;
   box-shadow: inset 2px 0px 0px #069CDE;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0px;
 }

 .menu-hori span.dropBottom {
   box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0px #069CDE;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   bottom: 0px;
 } 

 .menu-hori a:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
   color: black;
 }

 .menu-hori .icon {
   display: none;
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .menu-hori{
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 40px;
 height: auto;
 margin-top: 15px;
 padding: 0px;
 display: table;
 z-index: 100;
 background: grey;
 display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
 .menu-hori ul li{
  float: none;
 }
 
 .menu-hori ul li a{
  display: none; 
 }
 
 .menu-hori ul li a.icon{
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
 }
 
 .responsive ul li a{
   display: block;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-hori" id="myMenu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon"onclick="myResponsive()">☰</a></li>
     <li><a>BEVEILIGINGSCAMERA</a><span class="dropBottom"></span>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#" class="dropRight">Analoog</a>          
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#">irc10</a></li>    
           <li><a href="#">ird29</a></li>    
           <li><a href="#">ird1</a></li>  
         </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
     </li>
</div>
```

I've now added the code snippet to the question.. it's quite much now.. I would like to adjust my javascript so that the sub items are also opened when clicked, not hovered like it is right now.

Comment: You're adding css classes, the rules of which we can't see, to elements in your HTML that you haven't shown; how did you want us to help? Please: show us your "*[mcve]*" code so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: No idea, since the html isn't shown. The same way you show the hambuger menu? Do you have other css classes that represent the submenus? WE kinda have to know how they are hidden before we know how to unhide them.

Answer (score 0):

There is example jQuery code of simple two-steps menu.

```
 $('#cssmenu li.active').addClass('open').children('ul').show();
    $('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
      $(this).removeAttr('href');
      var element = $(this).parent('li');
      if (element.hasClass('open')) {
        element.removeClass('open');
        element.find('li').removeClass('open');
        element.find('ul').slideUp(200);
      } else {
        element.addClass('open');
        element.children('ul').slideDown(200);
        element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp(200);
        element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
        element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
        element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp(200);
      }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li class="active has-sub open"><a href="#">Products</a>
      <ul>
         <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Product 1</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Sub Product</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Sub Product</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Product 2</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Sub Product</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Sub Product</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/dkarasiewicz/pen/VprRNK)